# Opacity Gradient Applied to CALayer?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, calayer

I basically want the opacity of every layer in my UITableView instance to "fade out" at the top 10 or so pixels.

Is there any way to fade out a CALayer (or more generally, a UIView)'s opacity? It'd be similar in effect to adding a shadow with a CAGradientLayer but instead of covering the table view's other layers with another, it would apply a filter to them to make them transparent according to a gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by using the `CALayer`'s `mask` property, but it's rather inefficient. Typically this sort of effect is done by overlaying a gradient that goes from transparent to the background color on top of your view (but this only works if you know what your background is).

Comment: Perfect - thanks! Unfortunately, my background isn't a solid colour but a dynamic image. I'm only doing this for one view onscreen at a time, but I'll check it out in Instruments before I ship. 

I had to create a CALayer to hold an opacity CAGradient layer for the fade and another plain CALayer for the rest of the view to be visible, but it looks fantastic!

Thanks again!

Comment: @AshFurrow: Glad to hear it worked. `mask` is relatively expensive, but when you need it, it tends to do the job. If you're having performance issues and you're not animating anything you might want to look into the `shouldRasterize` flag. That can help static content perform better under certain circumstances. But of course if you're animating then it's not going to be good.